Meanings of "più mf" and "meno mp"
I am confused here:
Does "più mf" mean "louder than mf" or "more moderately loud than mf" (that is, "quiter than mf")?
And does "meno mp" mean "softer then mp" (that is, "quieter than mp") or "less moderately soft" (that is, "louder than mp")?

Where are you seeing these? E.g., composer and title?

Lol; "Moderately; even more moderately; as moderately as possible." (or "All dynamics are moderate, but some are more moderate than others.") I'm going to guess you're simply dealing with a confused score.

@Aaron - Like in Debussy's "Prélude à l'après-midi d'un faune": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnz4T33Jl7I&t=366s (first bar, in the first and second staves you have "più p" there).

@AndyBonner - Whoud you call Debussy's "Prélude à l'après-midi d'un faune" a confused score (check my reply to Aaron right above)?

That’s the point: “soft” and “loud“ are concepts that can be gradated; you can have degrees of softness and loudness. But “degrees of moderateness” is problematic.

@AndyBonner - Aaaaaah! I got it now. Thank you!

@AndyBonner everything in moderation, including moderation!

"più" translates literally to "more" in English.

@M - I understand that, but the question was when you add it to something like "moderately loud", you don't know whether it is "more moderately" or "more loud".

@brilliant: The example you gave above turned out to be “più p”.  Have you also actually come across examples with “più mf” or “meno mp” as you suggest in the title?  If you have, it would be helpful to post them — otherwise the whole discussion is rather academic.


Like in Debussy's "Prélude à l'après-midi d'un faune": youtube.com/watch?v=vnz4T33Jl7I&t=366s (first bar, in the first and second staves you have "più p" there).

Più p is decidedly not the same as più mp, and I doubt you will ever see più with mp or mf,  It would be a bit odd even to see più pp or più ff, just as you wouldn't say in English "more very loud," but I would not rule out the possibility.
Più p means "softer"; it has no absolute meaning.  For example, if you see it after pp then it means "somewhere between pp and ppp.  If you see it after mp then it means "somewhere between mp and p, and so on.
(In addition to più p and più f, there are also meno p and meno f, where meno means "less.")

But what then "più" and "meno" are for?

Più and meno are related to the words "plus" and "minus" and they are used in Italian to form the comparative.  This is also used frequently for tempo: in addition to più piano and più forte, softer and louder, you also have più mosso and meno mosso, faster and slower, and, in general, you can combine it with any adjective, such as più semplice, simpler, and più complicato, more complicated.

"there are also meno p and meno f, where meno means "less."" - Would "meno p" mean "less soft", in other words, "louder"?

@brilliant yes, though (without having done a survey) my sense is that meno p is probably rare.  On the other hand, meno f is fairly common.

This seems to confuse two different dynamic concepts: mp and mf mean a sort of absolute medium dynamic. più/meno forte/piano are indicating changes of dynamics: It is for example possible to have p to call for a slight increase, you can do p, then poco più forte, or even poco più forte ma sempre p.
But doing più/meno mf/mp does not really make sense without a lot of context. Because mf and mp contain two contradicting indications: Loud or soft, and medium or moderate. So what does the più/meno refer to? The loud/soft? Or the medium?
Within some context there can be a clear reading: If you are f, then you have poco mf, then più mf it is clear that this is an indication for going softer. But if you have say mp and then più mf it should probably be read as going louder, but still not fully mf.
But you see, such indications are hard to interpret and require a lot of context, so one should really avoid doing so and keep to standard terms such as più forte — if necessary with some additional indication such as poco più forte (second above example could read as poco più forte ma non tanto mf if really necessary).

+1 for all that. Dynamic signs are relative, and are really an indication of what the composer would like, or used to play for the piece. Better, really, to go by feel, and use the 'directions' as guides rather than 'thou shalt play at this volume', I think.

Thank you for your answer. Can you, please, then answer how I could specify a dynamic that is not as loud (intense) as mf, yet not as quiet (soft) as mp (that is, between mp and mf)? Or, for example, not as loud (intense) as f, yet not as quiet (soft) as mf (that is, between mf and f).

@Brilliant - there's really no need to. From fff to ppp  there are 8 choices of dynamics, and I challenge anyone tom differentiate between any neighbouring ones accurately.

@Tim - But what then "più" and "meno" are for?

They're for someone who's really picky..?!

@Tim - :) Like Debussy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnz4T33Jl7I&t=366s  (first bar, in the first and second staves you have "più p" there).

@brilliant - For your first example, you probably have to go with mf, then "più piano" or mp, then "più forte". I generally use "più forte" only to provide contrasting dynamics within the same level, not jump between levels, and I generally only use "più piano" to negate "più forte".

@Dekkadeci - Interesting! Thank you.

“ how I could specify a dynamic that is not as loud (intense) as mf, yet not as quiet (soft) as mp (that is, between mp and mf)?” — this deserves to be its own question, and maybe is the one that you were really looking for in the first place? The answers would be very different than this rather abstract discussion, and would have to do with players’ interpretation of dynamics.

@AndyBonner - "this deserves to be its own question..." OK. I just asked it here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/137590/how-i-could-specify-a-dynamic-that-is-not-as-loud-intense-as-mf-yet-not-as-qu      However, it looks like you've already given me a valid answer to it here in one of your comments above.
