How I could specify a dynamic that is not as loud (intense) as mf, yet not as quiet (soft) as mp?
Sometimes, epecially in my music editor, I stumble upon this need. I have no idea, though, how this need is really valid in real-life music situation.

Closely related (if not a duplicate): 1. How should I notate an intermediate dynamic between mp and mf?, 2. What's the name, and symbol, for the "normal" dynamic volume? (between mp and mf)

Are you trying to give a dynamic indication to software or a human performer?

You can't, really, except relatively, just as there is no absolute way to specify a volume midway between f and ff.
Inspired by your other recent question (Meanings of "più mf" and "meno mp") and its comments, I would suggest

mp followed by più f ma non mf
mf followed by meno f ma non mp

Depending on the desired effect and the reason for rejecting mp and mf, other solutions might include beginning the passage mp cresc. and ending it mf or, the other way around, beginning mf decresc. and ending mf.
If your goal is to affect the editor's playback of the piece, I suspect that this will not be effective.  In that case you would probably have to see whether the playback function is customizable, for example if you can alter the midi key velocity explicitly.

I see. Thank you.

Not far off my comment, really.

With "più forte", I put that indication in and adjust MIDI key velocity at the same time.

@brilliant I would say as a performer and composer this level of granularity seems a bit excessive to me. I would lean more on character markings (e.g., dolce) and artist interpretation. Disclaimer: I’m in the U.S. and here, dynamics are generally interpreted relatively across the piece, not absolutely between pieces.

@ToddWilcox - absolutely, as in my comment to the last question. With 8 grades to choose from, who would need more?

@Tim - You are right. I know little about the real-life situation in music. I got this question solely from my experience of playing with my music editor. It was there that this need of going further between those 8 grades became a valid one for me.

@brilliant Then it sounds like you're more interested in how to granularly alter the playback volume in your music editor than how to notate it for a performer. That's within this site's scope, as long as you mention relevant details like what software you're using.

@the-baby-is-you - Thanks for telling me that. For some reason I thought that this place was only for traditional music scoring. My editor is MuseScore Studio 4.4.2

@brilliant Ah. Unfortunately, while this was easily adjusted in MuseScore 3, MuseScore 4 has no such option (I would have choice words with the devs over this and more). The official word is to manually adjust the velocity of each affected note. I'm still using MS3, and I'm not the only one.

@the-baby-is-you - Yes. I've been solving this problem by creating same-instrument back-up staves. Not a perfect solution in terms of efficiency, but that's so far been the only way how to go about it.

Strange, so there is no "normal"? Only half strong or half quiet? I suggest "normal" or "lagom" then :)

@Emil "Lagom"?  In any event, the meaning of dynamic indications has varied significantly over the centuries.  In the beginning, there were only "piano" and "forte"; piano was a sort of special instruction that was used for echo passages and when accompanying a soloist, and forte was simply used to cancel the special instruction.  (This frequently leads modern conductors astray.)  So up to about the end of the 18th century, more or less, "forte" was "normal."

Yes, lagom is swedish for just the right amount, not too much, not to little. Interesting history lesson you gave.

@brilliant Dynamic notation is never absolute, and could never (nor should ever) be. For instance, the difference from "p" followed by "mp" may not be the same as "mf" and "f", and even within the same piece. As Todd mentions above, such level of "granularity" rarely makes sense in music (or scoring at least) and is always contextualized, even within the time lapse of a piece: a "poco più f" following a "mp" may change depending on what follows, and may be clarified with other symbols (eg. dashes) but will never be a performance absoluteness. Even the same markings can have different dynamics.

There's mezza voce, sometimes abbreviated to m. v..
